# VS code and CPP issues

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I write code in C++, it takes a very long time to run, more than a minute in one {cout} unlike any other language, all languages ​​work efficiently in addition to the appearance of those messages in the listed images..

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are opening a binary file in the editor, which is not what you want to do. The compiled file is non-text and VSCode cannot display it, except in hex-editor form

Comment: So what is the solution??@Chris

Comment: You can run the application from any terminal, including the VS Code terminals. So you could run "cmd" and change to the output directory - and then just enter test.exe. You could press ctrl-j and get a console there and do the same thing. You can run from explorer.exe by navigating and double clicking. You could configure Run->Add Configuration... and set it up to run - VSCode will open a console below to run it in. Personally for me I find 3 desktop windows and switching with ctrl-win-left/right great with VSCode on desktop 1, cmd for building on desktop 2 and cmd for running on desktop 3